# Get Current User ID from Mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I create a Users Database and users have `username`, `password` etc. And each one has a unique `auto_increment` id. I need this; For example if I login to the website it should be `$id= my_id`, if you login to the website it should be `$id= your_id`. Can you help please. Thanks.

I tried;

```
$result = mysql_query("select id from Users where username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);`

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your login code (when you define `$_SESSION['username']`) you should store the user ID in the session, with any other user related data that you need.

Comment: yea it gives id but you know username not unique, for example if two person who have same names, then is it working?

Comment: ooo I'm soooorry, ofcourse username unique thanks...

Comment: @OznOzi store the user ID in the session because this should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Two users should not have the same username, even if they have the different user_ids.

You need some background help on creating your registration/login system. This would be a very good resource and would help you a lot: [phpacademy.org Login/Registration Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECE134D877783367C7)

Please remember to upvote any posts that are helpful to you, and to choose an answer for your question when you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

add id feild in ur login check query . if login successful set that data in session or return to the login function . U get the id .

Answer (score 0):

Also store **user id** in to the `$_SESSION` array so that your user id will accessible in each request,
 use your query will look like

```
 $result = mysql_query("select username from Users where id ='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
```